# Finance car with or with out a balloon payment

Tags: loans, investing, car

A person called "Bob" is considering buying a car and financing it over 5 years.
He has the option to finance the car with a maximum balloon payment of 30%.
When financed the load will have an interest rate of 13%.

Bob also has a unit trust investment that historically (on paper) has had a growth of 15% per annum.

Which is the wisest choice for Bob to make:

- Buy the car with the balloon payment and invest the difference, then at the end pay the balloon payment off; and luckily have some money left.
- Buy the car without the balloon payment, fully financed

Bob isn't the best with finance so any other alternatives are most appreciated!

#### Edit

If in your opinion the difference between the investment growth and interest is too small to do the first option, then; how much should the difference be before the it starts to look like a good idea?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is about Bob's finances rather than personal finance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That interest rate (13%) is steep, and the balloon payment will have him paying more interest longer. Investing the difference is a risky proposition because past performance of an investment is no guarantee of future performance. Is taking that risk worth netting 2%? Not for me, but you must answer that last question for yourself.

**To your edit:** How disruptive would losing the car and/or getting negative marks on your credit be? If you can quantify that in dollars then you have your answer.

Comment: I totally agree with you. Bob is actually a friend, and this whole balloon payment scenario was brought forward to him by his financial adviser (which he followed). I basically told him the same as your answer here, and I really hoped that you would have backed the first option, but alas...

Comment: I would never advise anyone to borrow against a car or house to invest money in the market. If I were Bob, I would ask the financial adviser what his commission is on any investment that he is offering.